# random.sample & random.choice function not working in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to explore Python by running a bot for Instagram named
[InstaPy](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy). In this code I am trying to combine multiple uni codes and make
it to one comment bar in Instagram, but it is not happening.

**What I have tried:**

- random.sample method
- random.choices method

Here "@{}" means it will comment the users "username" in the comment box.

It is only commenting 1 emoji instead of 2 emojis.

**I expect it to comment 2 emojis.**

I am a noob at this
    `session.set_comments(my_comments,media='photo')`

#  "my_comments" represents the actual comment we want to make

**Here's my code:**

```py
my_comments = random.choices([u':blush: @{}',
                               u':smiley: @{}',
                               u':relaxed: @{}',
                               u':satisfied: @{}',
                               u':wink: @{}',
                               u':stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye: @{}',
                               u':stuck_out_tongue_closed_eyes: @{}',
                               u':grinning: @{}',
                               u':sweat_smile: @{}',
                               u':sunglasses: @{}',
                               u':smiling_imp: @{}',
                               u':innocent: @{}',
                               u':yellow_heart: nice one @{}',
                               u':blue_heart: nice @{}',
                               u':purple_heart: good one @{}',
                               u':heart: @{} good',
                               u':green_heart: @{} awesome',
                               u':sparkling_heart: @{} awesomeee',
                               u':sparkles: @{}',
                               u':star: @{}',
                               u':star2: @{}',
                               u':dizzy: @{}',
                               u':boom: @{}',
                               u':collision: @{}',
                               u':fire: @{}',
                               u':+1: @{}',
                               u':thumbsup: @{}',
                               u':ok_hand: @{}',
                               u':v: @{}',
                               u':point_up: @{}',
                               u':raised_hands: @{}',
                               u':clap: @{}',
                               u':muscle: @{}',
                               u':metal: @{}',
                               u':dancer: @{}',
                               u':dancers: @{}',
                               u':smiley_cat: @{}',
                               u':smile_cat: @{}',
                               u':eyes: @{}',
                               u':speech_balloon: @{} !!',
                               u':thought_balloon: @{}], k=2)`
    `session.set_comments(my_comments,media='photo')`
```

Comment: Did you check the output of your choices call? If that is correct your issue sounds like a wrong use of `.set_comments(...)` (whatever that is). And please fix your formatting and reduce your code example.

Comment: You are missing a closing ' on the :thought_balloon: emoji. Does changing this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Python `random` has no `choices` function. It has:

   - `choice` function, that returns one element: `random.choice([1,2,3])`
   - `sample` function, that returns several unique elements: `random.sample([1,2,3], 2)`

   You should use `sample` function if you want several unique elements and multiple `choice` functions if you want elements can be repeated.
2. You have several backquote symbols that are breaking your code:

```
                           u':thought_balloon: @{}], k=2)`
`session.set_comments(my_comments,media='photo')`
```

(Note the last symbols in the both lines and the first symbol in the second line)